# WMI Win32_Printer not working on XP Embedded

Tags: winapi, wmi, printing, windows-xp-embedded

I have some code which works on a standard XP system, but fails on XP
Embedded test machine.

I get System.Management.ManagementException : Provider Load Failure

Here is my code:

```
    string query = "Select * From Win32_Printer";
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();
```

Are there services to start or DLL's to register?

Please, help me find the answer!

Thanks in advance,
Flea

Answer (score 0):

You must check wich the `System.Management.Instrumentation.dll` library is properly registered.

try out this link

- [How to: Fix Provider Load Failure Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb961987%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!

The problem is that I'm working with .NET 2.0 and that library does't exist.